# pass parameter to javascript onload event from php

Tags: php, javascript, parameter-passing

I have a javascript code for countdown. I have a date which I gather from database usu php, I need to pass the date object ot javascript function but I don't know how. I tried this:

```
<body onload="countIt(<?php echo $event->startDate;?>)">
```

but it doesn't seem to work. here is the js code that I have

```
function countIt(date) {
    ///i will parse the date into below variables if I can get the date.
    year = 2013;
    month = 09;
    day = 28;
    hours = 12;
    minutes = 00;
    seconds = 00;

    setTimeout(function() {
        endDate = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, 00);
        thisDate = new Date();
        thisDate = new Date(thisDate.getFullYear(), thisDate.getMonth() + 1, thisDate.getDay(), thisDate.getHours(), thisDate.getMinutes(), thisDate.getSeconds(), 00, 00);

        var daysLeft = parseInt((endDate - thisDate) / 86400000);
        var hoursLeft = parseInt((endDate - thisDate) / 3600000);
        var minutsLeft = parseInt((endDate - thisDate) / 60000);
        var secondsLeft = parseInt((endDate - thisDate) / 1000);

        seconds = minutsLeft * 60;
        seconds = secondsLeft - seconds;

        minutes = hoursLeft * 60;
        minutes = minutsLeft - minutes;

        hours = daysLeft * 24;
        hours = (hoursLeft - hours) < 0 ? 0 : hoursLeft - hours;

        days = daysLeft;

        startCount(days, hours, minutes, seconds);
    }, 1000);
}

function startCount(days, hours, minutes, seconds) {
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "DAYS " + days + ", HOURS " + hours + ", MINUTES " + minutes + ", SECONDS: " + seconds;
    countIt();
}
```

Comment: are you seeing any errors (check the js console). Also can you give an example of the date that php is inserting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make javascript date object in multiple ways:

```
    var d = new Date();
    var d = new Date(milliseconds);
    var d = new Date(dateString);
    var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

So, one of the options could be:

```
    <body onload="countIt(<?php echo strtotime($event->startDate);?>)">
```

and at the begining of your function:

```
    var date = new Date(date);
```

That can work only if your $event->startDate is valid PHP date format. You can learn more about that [HERE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).